# How to "Require password change at next login" without resetting password

Tags: mac, ldap, openldap

When you reset an user's password in macOS Server.app's Open Directory (I think it's using `slapd`), you can also check the option `Require password change at next login`.

The question: can you also check that option somehow without changing the password? We want to enforce a new password policy, and require all users to change their password. Probably something on the command line.

(when you change the directory password, the local password hasn't changed, so that can be a bit complicated for the end user)

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Cannot force password changes](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7048779)
has this method:

> I had a similar issue (upgrading from Mavericks to Yosemite, started
>   on Saturday) and resolved it today by
>
> - exporting users and groups into a text file (you can do this from within server),
> - destroy the OD master,
> - delete all the certs,
> - restart
> - create a new master
> - import users from text file
> - import groups
>
> With this method, users will have to reset their passwords, but you
>   have all user ids, etc. preserved.
>
> The issue stems from the way OD is relying on certificates for
>   authentication. When you are creating the new master, the relevant
>   certificates are created to support OD. Just archiving and restoring
>   the OD master didn't help.